# To find the nullity of a matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $x = [ x_1 ,x_2, x_3]^T \in \mathbb R^3 $( T denotes the transpose) be a non zero vector and A $= x(x^T)/(x^T)x$. Then What is the nullity of A?

$xx^T$ is 3*3 matrix with nullity 2 and $(x^T)x$ is 1*1 nonzero matrix. A is defined as division of $xx^T$ and $(x^T)x$. Matrix division is not defined then how to solve this problem?

Comment: A $1 \times 1$ matrix can be treated as a scalar.

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: @Anurag A I didn't know this. Can 1*1 matrices be treated as scalars in all type of problems?

Comment: @Mathsaddict $1\times 1$ matrix is itself  a scalar always if entries are in field.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a matrix division. In fact $x^Tx=||x||_2^2$ where $||x||_p$ is the $p$-norm. The nullity of $A$ would be $$\{w\in\Bbb R^3|w^Tx=0\}$$which is a subspace of $\Bbb R^3$ of dimension $2$.